# Can anyone help me with this StackOverFlow.Exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a web application, made using c#/mvc/ef/unitofworkPattern.  I have database with two tables, PERSON and CASENOTE.  A PERSON may have multiple CASENOTES, but a CASENOTE may only have one PERSON.  The key in PERSON is PasNo.  This is a foreign key in CASENOTE, but it's not defined as a foreign key in DDL for reasons.

So, I have a search page, where someone can input data into a CASENOTE number textbox, and get back all people linked to any casenotes it may find.  So they could put in just a partial casenote, and it would get back all casenotes containing that partial string, and then find all of the PEOPLE that have those casenotes using the PasNo in each casenote.

So here is my code:

```
public IEnumerable<PERSON> GetSearchResults(SearchViewModel viewModel)
{
    var people = unitOfWork.PersonRepository.GetAll();
    if (viewModel.Casenote != null)
    {
        var casenotes = unitOfWork.CasenoteRepository.GetAll()
                            .Where(x => x.CASENOTE1.Trim()
                                   .ToLower()
                                   .Contains(viewModel.Casenote.Trim().ToLower()))
                            .Take(1000)
                            .ToList();

        if (casenotes.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var casenote in casenotes)
            {
                var pasint = casenote.PAS_INT_NO;
                people = people.Where(w => w.PAS_INT_NO == pasint);
                //it gives me the stackoverflow.exception at execution of the above line
            } 
        }
    }
    return people.Take(1000).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.SURNAME).ThenBy(x => x.FORENAMES);
}
```

Can anybody help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I can provide more info if needed.

**EDIT!**
I forgot to mention, when I put in a single letter into the CASENOTE textbox, I get the stackoverflow exception, but when I type more than 1 letter, I don't and the search works.

Comment: That's probably the number of casenotes returned then - how many results would you have? I don't think adding Wheres here is what you want to do, and I'd guess adding 1000 Wheres is the problem: note that this will be 'and', so you'll only get a result if all the casenotes have the same PAS_INT_NO. What you really want to do is to .Select the casenote PAS_INT_NOs into a list and then do a single .Where on people for that list .Contains(w.PAS_INT_NO), which will hopefully be converted into a SQL 'IN' clause.

Comment: What does the debugger say about the numbers and what the call stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to select from `people` using `or` condition over `w.PAS_INT_NO == pasint`, this would work:

```
public IEnumerable<PERSON> GetSearchResults(SearchViewModel viewModel)
{
    var people = unitOfWork.PersonRepository.GetAll();
    if (viewModel.Casenote != null)
    {
        var casenoteNos = unitOfWork.CasenoteRepository.GetAll()
                            .Where(x => x.CASENOTE1.Trim()
                                   .ToLower()
                                   .Contains(viewModel.Casenote.Trim().ToLower()))
                            .Select(casenote => casenote.PAS_INT_NO)
                            .Take(1000)
                            .ToList();

        if (casenoteNos.Any())
        {
            people = people.Where(w => casenoteNos.Contains(w.PAS_INT_NO));
        }
    }
    return people.Take(1000).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.SURNAME).ThenBy(x => x.FORENAMES);
}
```

**Description**

The culprit in the original code was:

```
people = people.Where(w => w.PAS_INT_NO == pasint)
```

because `IEnumerable` produced by `Where` is not materialized, here we creating up to 1000 chained `Where`, so eventually `people` becomes `people.Where(...).Where(...).Where...1000 times`.

If check the sources of `Where` extension [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/e56279724ddb2715ab3c18c47ecd3b78eb90d3c7/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L15), first `Where` produces `WhereEnumerableIterator` object then its `Where` and consequent `Where`s generate nested lambda calls [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/e56279724ddb2715ab3c18c47ecd3b78eb90d3c7/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L165) by calling [CombinePredicates](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/e56279724ddb2715ab3c18c47ecd3b78eb90d3c7/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L61), which is:

```
static Func<TSource, bool> CombinePredicates<TSource>(Func<TSource, bool> predicate1, Func<TSource, bool> predicate2) {
    return x => predicate1(x) && predicate2(x);
}
```

Which being called 1000 times becomes:

```
(x=> ...1000 times... (x => predicate1(x) && predicate2(x)) && predicate2(x)) ...1000 times... ) && predicate2(x)
```

Then 1000 nested calls produced a stack overflow exception.

Conclusion: don't chain a ton of `Where`, it was not designed for that. Anyway chained `Where` (a ton of `AND` filters) here is not what was intended, but `IN` / `Contains` is needed instead.

Comment: @ailinmcc666, I've updated my answer with a description

Comment: Thank you, great explanation @Renat

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are getting a list of all the people at the top of the function? I'm not that familiar with EF so this syntax could be wrong, but I'm assuming that this would be much more efficient than getting every person in your database and then filtering that list:

```
        foreach (var casenote in casenotes)
        {
            var pasint = casenote.PAS_INT_NO;
            people = unitOfWork.PersonRepository.Where(w => w.PAS_INT_NO == pasint);
            //it gives me the stackoverflow.exception at execution of the above line
        }
```

Not sure if this will solve the problem, but if there are a lot of people and a lot of casenotes in your database that could definitely cause a SO exception.